# Lost connection to MySQL server during query (5.6.20)

Tags: mysql

I have a brand new install of MySQL 5.6.20 and now get these messages from my front-end when I am loading up the new database.

```
[Err] 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query
[Err] Alter table address add Foreign Key (zip) references zip (zip) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
```

This is what the log is saying

> 2014-09-24 22:26:23 4091 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for
>   table '"foo"."author"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace
>   with space id 56.
>
> 2014-09-24 22:26:23 82eb68c00  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2
>   in a file operation. InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find
>   the path specified.
>
> 2014-09-24 22:26:23 4091 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid
>   tablespace file for 'foo/author'. See
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html
>   for how to resolve the issue.
>
> 2014-09-24 22:26:23 4091 [Warning] InnoDB: Orphan table encountered
>   during DROP DATABASE. This is possible if 'foo/author.frm' was lost.
>
> 2014-09-24 22:26:23 4091 [Warning] InnoDB: Missing foo/author.ibd file
>   for table foo/author.

I've never seen this before. If I load the exact same database on an older version of MySQL on a totally different machine, it loads just fine. I've increased the `max_allowed_packet` variable to 64M but this didn't help.

The SQL is comprised of CREATE TABLE statements and then after the tables are created, then the Alter table statements are executed.

Has anyone else run into this issue with 5.6.20? If so, what is the fix?

Comment: Did you try alter table import tablespace ? make sure all tables are imported correctly especially if you use InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced it, but it could look like the query broke mid transaction

- Try and see if you can force the transaction to continue.
- Try and just commit, see if that opens up.
- And last but not least, try and rollback and see if that could free the transaction.

Thats my 5 cents.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-recovery.html